# Gmail One Click Action with 4 hashtags ##Hash## not working

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, microdata, json-ld

I want to implement a Gmail Action ([One-Click Action: `ConfirmAction`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action#confirm_action)) which gets shown as a button in the inbox of Gmail for users to confirm their email adress. Gmail provides a JSON-LD solution and a MICRODATA solution. In both cases I have trouble with the URL I need to put. My URL has 4 hashtag characters (#), when I just put one (#Hash) the button shows up correctly but when I put the correct URL (##Hash##) the button does not show. *(Testing it with the Google Apps Script Editor.)*

JSON-LD

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Confirm email",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://link.example.com/account/email/verify?h=##Hash##"
    }
  },
  "description": "Approval of mail adress"
}
</script>
```

MICRODATA

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ConfirmAction">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Confirm email"/>
    <div itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
      <link itemprop="url" href="https://link.example.com/account/email/verify?h=##Hash##"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Approval of mail adress"/>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It a bit strange to use #s like that? They are a reserved URL character, so their use could cause issues. e.g. Browsers strip out all content from a # before making requests.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath You are correct, thank you. The final product mail will have a different URL with no hash.